# Struct price filter doesn't give anything if the first product is not in the range

Tags: c

The idea is simple, filter and print the phones that are inside the price range, but now it only works as intented when the first phone of the list is inside the price range. For example if minimum price is set to 100 and max 600, it prints the first two. But if the min price is set to over 125 it prints nothing. (If the first phone isn't in the price range).

I'm sure someone here can help me with this, as the subject is simple and solution probably is quickly noticeable by more experienced people.

Heres the code i've came up with, I'm a beginner so don't flame please

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct mobile {
    char manu [20];
    char model [20];
    float price;
} Mobile;

int main(void)
{
    int min,max;
    int i=0;
    Mobile phone[5] = {
        {"Nokia", "5120", 125},
        {"OnePlus", "6", 529},
        {"Apple", "iPhone 6", 999},
        {"Apple", "iPhone x", 1199}
    };
    printf("Give min price: ");
    scanf("%i", &min);
    printf("Give max price: ");
    scanf("%i", &max);
    printf ("%-20s %-15s Price\n" ,"Phone manufacturer","Phone model");

    while(phone[i].price >= min && phone[i].price <= max)
    {
        printf("\n%-20s %-15s %6.2f\n", phone[i].manu, phone[i].model, phone[i].price);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the strangest `C#` I have ever seen...

Comment: I'm thinking this is [tag:c++]? If not please fix the tag according.

Comment: No this is C language.

Comment: Your `while` loop exits immediately when the condition is false, that's not how you filter. Also the loop can potentially access the array out of bounds, invoking *undefined behavior*

Comment: You are getting an exception because the variable i is getting larger than the size of the array which is 4 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop will stop as soon as it finds a price that is not within range.  And if it doesn't find a price out of range, it will read past the end of the array, invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

What you want is to loop over all elements of the array, then inside the loop use an `if` to determine whether or not to print.

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    if (phone[i].price >= min && phone[i].price <= max) {
        printf("\n%-20s %-15s %6.2f\n", phone[i].manu, phone[i].model, phone[i].price);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks alot for the help :D Sorry people if my code is hard to read, I've started only a bit over a month ago..

Comment: @esa Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.